# How to improve bulk mysql insert with php to grab all directories and images from directory at once

Tags: php, mysql, image, insert, directory

I got a working image from directory to mysql inserting script.the problem is that i after every directory i need to change the name in script itself to insert next images from other directory. every file and every diretory with images is in a prent directory called "images". so my question how can i say insert everything in the mysql db from this directory and use the names of the directory as category names for images in it.

```
<?php
$server = 'xxxxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxx';
$dbname = 'xxxxxxx';

$connect = mysql_connect($server,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect);





$path = "images/thanks/";
$files = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',array_filter(glob("{$path}*.*"),'is_file'));

if(empty($files)){
    echo "There were no matching files to insert into the database.";
} else {    
    $insertValues = array();
foreach($files as $file)

{
$data = getimagesize($file);
$width = $data[0];
$height = $data[1];
    $insertValues[] = "('Titel', 'thanks', '{$file}', '$width', '$height')";
}$query = "INSERT INTO `gbpics` (`gbpictitel`, `gbpiccat`, `gbpicurl`, `gbpicwidth`, `gbpicheight`) VALUES " . implode(', ', $insertValues);
    if(!mysql_query($query)){
        echo "There was a problem inserting the data.";
        trigger_error("Query failed: $query<br />Error: " . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "The data was inserted successfully.";
    }
}?>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you post this on code-review first.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php
$server = 'xxxxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxx';
$dbname = 'xxxxxxx';

$connect = mysql_connect($server, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $connect);




$dirs = array_filter(glob('images/*'), 'is_dir');
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    $path  = "images/" . $dir . "/";
    $files = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_filter(glob("{$path}*.*"), 'is_file'));

    if (empty($files)) {
        echo "There were no matching files to insert into the database.";
    } else {
        $insertValues = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $data           = getimagesize($file);
            $width          = $data[0];
            $height         = $data[1];
            $insertValues[] = "('Titel', {$dir}, '{$file}', '$width', '$height')";
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO `gbpics` (`gbpictitel`, `gbpiccat`, `gbpicurl`, `gbpicwidth`, `gbpicheight`) VALUES " . implode(', ', $insertValues);
        if (!mysql_query($query)) {
            echo "There was a problem inserting the data.";
            trigger_error("Query failed: $query<br />Error: " . mysql_error());
        } else {
            echo "The data was inserted successfully.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

btw you have pretty deprecated code here...
dont use `mysql_` use `mysqli_`

Comment: hi friend yes i will suggest that but script isnt working he gives me error thousand times like this "There were no matching files to insert into the database.". Got an Idea? my upload file is in root my category folders in the main folder images so it should work cant figure out why not.. pls help @RiazLaskar